# How to pass the phone number from Intl-Tel-Input to an input on Ruby-on-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intl-tel-input

I have a simple_form with a phone number. I'm using Intl-Tel-Input to get the entire phone_number and confirm SMS in different countries (twilio). In console.log, I succeed to display the entire number. When I submit, I just get the phone_number without the country indicator (dial_code)

I read the doc, tried to get it by other way (.value, .data, etc...), but impossible to save the entire phone_number (for example, +33612345678, I just get 61234567).

Here's my code :

```
    <div class="userphonenumber">
      <%= f.input :phone_number, label: 'N° de téléphone', required: true, autofocus: true ,
      input_html: { autocomplete: "intlNumber" }, wrapper_html: { id: 'userphonenumber' }%>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
  $("#user_phone_number").intlTelInput({
    formatOnInit: true,
    separateDialCode: true,
    onlyCountries: ['fr', 'at', 'be', 'bg', 'cz', 'dk', 'de', 'ee', 'ie', 'el', 'es', 'hr', 'it', 'cy', 'lv', 'lt', 'lu', 'hu', 'mt', 'nl', 'pl', 'pt', 'ro', 'si', 'sk', 'fi', 'se', 'uk'],
    initialCountry: "fr"
  });

  const flag = document.querySelector(".flag-container")
  flag.addEventListener("click", () => {
  var intlNumber = $("#user_phone_number").intlTelInput("getNumber");
  console.log("intlNumber", intlNumber)

  var input = document.querySelector("#user_phone_number");
  window.intlTelInput(input);

  });
</script>
```

I'm expecting to get +33612345678 to use the phone_number with twilio. Beginner on RoR and JS. Did I miss something ? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Finally fix with this solution :

```
<script>
  $("#user_phone_number").intlTelInput({
    formatOnInit: true,
    separateDialCode: true,
    onlyCountries: ['at', 'be', 'bg', 'cz', 'dk', 'de', 'ee', 'ie', 'el', 'es', 'fr', 'hr', 'it', 'cy', 'lv', 'lt', 'lu', 'hu', 'mt', 'nl', 'pl', 'pt', 'ro', 'si', 'sk', 'fi', 'se', 'uk'],
    initialCountry: "fr",
  });

  var phone = document.getElementById('user_phone_number')
  phone.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    console.log(event)
  });

  $("form").submit(function() {
  $('#user_phone_number').val($(phone).intlTelInput("getNumber"));
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".form").submit( function(eventObj) {
     $("<input />").attr("type", "hidden")
    .attr("name", "ccode")
    .attr("value", $(this).find(".selected-dial-code").text())
    .appendTo(".form");
     return true;
});
```